# YOLOv3) compiles and run. But no predictions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo, darknet

I'm using macOS Catalina.

I'm just following the basic tutorial which are written in the [Darknet page](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/).

when I run the command

```
$make
$./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg
```

then the Yolo is not predict after just showing the running time

```
Loading weights from yolov3.weights...Done!
data/dog.jpg: Predicted in 19.215062 seconds.
```

Also, prediction.jpg is saved without any boundary box

I tried also

```
$./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg -thresh 0
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ seems to be more appropriate for this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `detect` command, the prediction is saved as an image instead of showing any log. Look into the current data folder, there should be an image named `predictions.jpg`. This image contains all the bounding boxes with classes.

If you want to print your predictions, you can use `darknet.py` file inside darknet folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
However, the predictions.jpg is not containg bounding boxes and classes.

Comment: That means your model didn't predict any objects in the image, try with some other image.

Comment: I've tried all the sample images provided from them and decrease thresh to 0, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right!
I reinstalled the weight. and it works!
I never thought about the weight file because it was loaded successfully.
Thank you very much:)